# Receiving PushKit VoIP notifications iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, pushkit

I'm integrating `PushKit` into my `iOS` app and have the client side code ready. I'm registering using `PKPushRegistry` and receiving the `PKPushCredential` with a token in my delegate. I'm registering this token to my server which is communicating with `APNS`.

I can't find good documentation on what to send from my server to `APNS` to send a `VoIP` push notification to the client. Do I just send a normal remote notification request with content-available:1 to push by just replacing my Remote Notifications `.pem` with my `VoIP .pem`?

Comment: Does it worked?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for asking this question.

Please read some useful information about Apple `PushKit` below or you can also read from Apple [official page](https://developer.apple.com/reference/pushkit).

> The PushKit framework provides the classes for your iOS apps to
>   receive pushes from remote servers. Pushes can be of one of two types:
>   standard and VoIP. Standard pushes can deliver notifications just as
>   in previous versions of iOS. VoIP pushes provide additional
>   functionality on top of the standard push that is needed to VoIP apps
>   to perform on-demand processing of the push before displaying a
>   notification to the user.

1. Apple `PushKit` is not a simple APNS, It's a Silent push
   notification so your            App not react when you have received
   the push notification.
2. We need to schedule `UILocalNotification` manually when you will
       receive a push from the server.
3. Display content you want to show the user in `UILocalNotification`

Some well known App use `PushKit` for notification such as **WhatsApp, Skype**.

Send only useful information which will be used to generate a local notification.

Comment: True, Pushkit notification will not show directly in notification center. @Dev you have to schedule local notification too , to get notification in notification center. also you need to give background and VOIP permission at client side.

Comment: Excuse me, how do we get the information about "Pushkit is a silent notification" from developer.apple.com? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use this simplepush.php file

```
<?php

// Put your device token here (without spaces):


      $deviceToken = '1234567890123456789';
//


// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'ProjectName';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'My first push notification!';



$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'PemFileName.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
//  'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body

$body['aps'] = array(
                     'content-available'=> 1,
                     'alert' => $message,
                     'sound' => 'default',
                     'badge' => 0,
                     );



// Encode the payload as JSON

$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

Use below commands to create pem file and use it in above code

```
$ openssl x509 -in aps_development.cer -inform der -out PushCert.pem

# Convert .p12 to .pem. Enter your pass pharse which is the same pwd that you have given while creating the .p12 certificate. PEM pass phrase also same as .p12 cert.  
$ openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out PushKey1.pem -in pushkey.p12

Enter Import Password:

MAC verified OK

Enter PEM pass phrase:

Verifying - Enter PEM pass phrase:

# To remove passpharse for the key to access globally. This only solved my stream_socket_client() & certificate capath warnings.
$ openssl rsa -in PushKey1.pem -out PushKey1_Rmv.pem

Enter pass phrase for PushChatKey1.pem:

writing RSA key

# To join the two .pem file into one file:
$ cat PushCert.pem PushKey1_Rmv.pem > ApnsDev.pem
```

After that go to simplepush.php location and fire command -> php simplepush.php

This way you can test your push kit notification setup architecture.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial

[Download](https://drive.google.com/a/brainvire.com/file/d/0B7ooURy3zGWKaGxGZVV4X0Y0d3M/view)

```
import UIKit
import PushKit


class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate,PKPushRegistryDelegate{



func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {


    let types: UIRemoteNotificationType = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]
    application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(types)

    self. PushKitRegistration()

    return true
}



//MARK: - PushKitRegistration

func PushKitRegistration()
{

    let mainQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue()
    // Create a push registry object
    if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {

        let voipRegistry: PKPushRegistry = PKPushRegistry(queue: mainQueue)

        // Set the registry's delegate to self

        voipRegistry.delegate = self

        // Set the push type to VoIP

        voipRegistry.desiredPushTypes = [PKPushTypeVoIP]

    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }


}


@available(iOS 8.0, *)
func pushRegistry(registry: PKPushRegistry!, didUpdatePushCredentials credentials: PKPushCredentials!, forType type: String!) {
    // Register VoIP push token (a property of PKPushCredentials) with server

    let hexString : String = UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>(start: UnsafePointer(credentials.token.bytes),
        count: credentials.token.length).map { String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joinWithSeparator("")

    print(hexString)


}


@available(iOS 8.0, *)
func pushRegistry(registry: PKPushRegistry!, didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload payload: PKPushPayload!, forType type: String!) {
    // Process the received push
    // From here you have to schedule your local notification

}

}
```

Comment: Is the binary message stream_socket_client approach still recommended? Shouldn't we be sending push notifications from the server using the new http/2 system?